# How to get a state value from one file and pass it to another in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am trying to change parts of a UI depending on a state from another file.

I have this component

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import Button from '../components/button';
import { getData } from '../utils/debugger';

// Make a separate function for axios call so that you can reuse it
function queryData(dropdownValue) {
  return axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: `http://xxx/zzz/${dropdownValue}`,
  })
    .then((res) => res.data.map((k) => k['key']['name']))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}

class InputForm extends React.Component {
  // Just use the state property. No need to use constructor
  state = {
    isLoaded: false,
    dropdown: 'RTS',
    value: '',
    data: [],
  };

  // If you use arrow function then you don't have to
  // bind them in the constructor

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  };

  handleDropdown = async (event) => {
    // Here we need to query the data from axios
    // If we get the data then we'll update the state
    // otherwise you may show any error message
    const value = event.target.value;

    try {
      const newData = await queryData(value);
      this.setState({ data: newData, dropdown: value });

      if (newData.length > 0) {
        this.setState({ value: newData[0] });
      }
      console.log('newData = ' + JSON.stringify(newData));
    } catch (ex) {
      console.error('Could not get data from axios');
    }
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    queryData(this.state.dropdown)
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ data: data });
        if (data && data.length > 0) {
          this.setState({ value: data[0] });
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.setState({ isLoaded: false });
        // Do other stuff here, may be show any error message?
        // Could not get data
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className='flex items-center'>
        <select
          value={this.state.dropdown}
          onChange={this.handleDropdown}
          className='relative w-full bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm px-1 py-3 text-center cursor-default focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm mr-5'>
          <option value='RTS'>RTS</option>
          <option value='RTB'>RTB</option>
          <option value='MPC'>MPC</option>
          <option value='MPC_DSP'>MPC_DSP</option>
        </select>

        <select
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          className='relative w-full bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm px-1 py-3 text-left cursor-default focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm mr-5'>
          {this.state.data.map((r) => (
            <option key={r} value={r}>
              {r}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>

        {console.log('---')}
        {console.log('these will be entered into the getData()')}
        {console.log(`this.state.dropdown = ${this.state.dropdown}`)}
        {console.log(`this.state.value = ${this.state.value}`)}

        <Button onClick={() => getData(this.state.dropdown, this.state.value)} color='green'>
          Generate
        </Button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default InputForm;
```

I want to take the value from `this.state.dropdown` everytime it's changed and pass it into another file and turn what I currently have...which works on button click.

```
const [buttonStatus, setButtonStatus] = useState('rts');

  const switchButtons = (x) => {
    setButtonStatus(x);
  };

  let buttonName = 'RTS / MPC DSP';
  let buttons;

  if (buttonStatus === 'rts') {
    buttonName = 'RTS / MPC DSP';
    buttons = <RTSButtons />;
  } else if (buttonStatus === 'rtb') {
    buttonName = 'RTB';
    buttons = <RTBButtons />;
  } else if (buttonStatus === 'mpc') {
    buttonName = 'MPC';
    buttons = <MPCButtons />;
  }
```

To something like this:

```
 if (this.state.dropdown === 'RTS') {
    return <RTSButtons />;
  } else if (this.state.dropdown === 'RTB') {
    return <RTBButtons />;
  } ...
```

I basically want to return something different everytime the state of `this.state.dropdown` is changed

I have racked my brains over this many times...never comp up trumps can anyone suggest a way to do it?

### My file structure

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── craco.config.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── logo192.png
│   ├── logo512.png
│   ├── manifest.json
│   └── robots.txt
├── src
│   ├── App.js <-- where i want to pass this.state.dropdown
│   ├── App.test.js
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── alert.js
│   │   ├── button.js
│   │   ├── input.js <-- where this.state.dropdown lives
│   │   ├── mpcButtons.js
│   │   ├── rtbButtons.js
│   │   ├── rtsButtons.js
│   │   └── select.js
│   ├── index.css
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── logo.svg
│   ├── reportWebVitals.js
│   ├── setupTests.js
│   └── utils
│       └── debugger.js
└── tailwind.config.js
```

### index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <script src='http://localhost:8097'></script>
    <div className='flex flex-col min-h-screen'>
      <header>
        <nav className='bg-gray-800'>
          <div className='mx-auto px-8'>
            <div className='flex items-center justify-between h-20'>
              <div>
                <span className='text-white font-bold'>Easy Debugger UI</span>
              </div>

              <div className=''>
                <Input />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>

      <div className='container mx-auto'>
        <Flasher>
          <Alert />
        </Flasher>
        <main>
          <App />
        </main>
      </div>
      <footer className='mt-10'></footer>
    </div>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

## Update

I have tried to use `useContext` and looked through some YT videos but I dont think I am getting it...well clearly I am not. ha

```
// input.js
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import Button from '../components/button';
import { getData } from '../utils/debugger';
import { DropdownContext } from '../utils/DropdownContext';

// Make a separate function for axios call so that you can reuse it
function queryData(dropdownValue) {
  return axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: `http://xxx/debugger/${dropdownValue}`,
  })
    .then((res) => res.data.map((k) => k['key']['name']))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}

class InputForm extends React.Component {
  // Just use the state property. No need to use constructor
  state = {
    isLoaded: false,
    dropdown: 'RTS',
    value: '',
    data: [],
  };

  // If you use arrow function then you don't have to
  // bind them in the constructor

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  };

  handleDropdown = async (event) => {
    // Here we need to query the data from axios
    // If we get the data then we'll update the state
    // otherwise you may show any error message
    const value = event.target.value;

    try {
      const newData = await queryData(value);
      this.setState({ data: newData, dropdown: value });

      if (newData.length > 0) {
        this.setState({ value: newData[0] });
      }
      console.log('newData = ' + JSON.stringify(newData));
    } catch (ex) {
      console.error('Could not get data from axios');
    }
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    queryData(this.state.dropdown)
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ data: data });
        if (data && data.length > 0) {
          this.setState({ value: data[0] });
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.setState({ isLoaded: false });
        // Do other stuff here, may be show any error message?
        // Could not get data
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <DropdownContext.Provide value={this.state.dropdown}>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className='flex items-center'>
          <select
            value={this.state.dropdown}
            onChange={this.handleDropdown}
            className='relative w-full bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm px-1 py-3 text-center cursor-default focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm mr-5'>
            <option value='RTS'>RTS</option>
            <option value='RTB'>RTB</option>
            <option value='MPC'>MPC</option>
            <option value='MPC_DSP'>MPC_DSP</option>
          </select>

          <select
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            className='relative w-full bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm px-1 py-3 text-left cursor-default focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm mr-5'>
            {this.state.data.map((r) => (
              <option key={r} value={r}>
                {r}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>

          {console.log('---')}
          {console.log('these will be entered into the getData()')}
          {console.log(`this.state.dropdown = ${this.state.dropdown}`)}
          {console.log(`this.state.value = ${this.state.value}`)}

          <Button onClick={() => getData(this.state.dropdown, this.state.value)} color='green'>
            Generate
          </Button>
        </form>
      </DropdownContext.Provide>
    );
  }
}

export default InputForm;
```

```
// App.js
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';

import './index.css';

import Button from '../src/components/button';

import RTSButtons from '../src/components/rtsButtons';
import RTBButtons from '../src/components/rtbButtons';
import MPCButtons from '../src/components/mpcButtons';

import { DropdownContext } from '../src/utils/DropdownContext';

const sectionStyles = 'mt-5 border-b pb-5';

export default function App() {
  const [buttonStatus, setButtonStatus] = useState('rts');
  const dropdownState = useContext(DropdownContext);

  const switchButtons = (x) => {
    setButtonStatus(x);
  };

  let buttonName = 'RTS / MPC DSP';
  let buttons;

  if (buttonStatus === 'rts') {
    buttonName = 'RTS / MPC DSP';
    buttons = <RTSButtons />;
  } else if (buttonStatus === 'rtb') {
    buttonName = 'RTB';
    buttons = <RTBButtons />;
  } else if (buttonStatus === 'mpc') {
    buttonName = 'MPC';
    buttons = <MPCButtons />;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <section id='response' className={`flex justify-between ${sectionStyles}`}>
        <div>
          <Button onClick={() => switchButtons('rts')} color='gray'>
            RTS / MPC DSP
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={() => switchButtons('rtb')} color='gray'>
            RTB
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={() => switchButtons('mpc')} color='gray'>
            MPC
          </Button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Button color='red'>
            <a href='http://exchange-debugger' target='_blank' rel='noreferrer'>
              create a capture
            </a>
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={() => console.log('Feedback was giving')} color='purple'>
            <a
              href='https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfzebOfAeXqGLqAp5E1l2fW1nTqSzYRwpqKG56HPXey9GQLcA/viewform'
              target='_blank'
              rel='noreferrer'>
              feedback
            </a>
          </Button>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section>
        <h2 className='font-bold text-2xl capitalize -mb-10 mt-2'>{buttonName}</h2>
        {dropdownState}
      </section>

      <section>{buttons}</section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
// DropdownContext.js
import { createContext } from 'react';

export const DropdownContext = createContext(null);
```

These are my components but i am getting the following error:

**Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of `InputForm`.**

I am not too sure where to look next any one can assit that would be great

Comment: How is that "other file" related here?  Don't think of your structure in terms of "files", think of it in terms of the hierarchy of components being rendered.  In what way does one relate to the other here?  Are both of these components even rendering at the same time?  In general you have two options for components to share state... Either pass the state from the parent to the child as a prop or use a global state manager like Redux or useContext.

Comment: the other file is App.js - just updated my question with a structure tree

Comment: If a top-level component (like `<App/>`) needs to know the state of a much lower-level component then you would "lift state up" and maintain it in that top-level component, passing it to the lower-level component(s) as props.  Alternatively, take a look at tools like Redux or useContext which maintain a more global, disconnected state.  With that, multiple components can pull the same state value from the global state store.

Comment: Thanks for the direction @David but i have seem to come up blanks again. I have updated my question